# Is there a better way of dynamically adding classes in Vue than this?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass

So I'm a noob at Vue.js and i'm trying to change the border colour of a card depending on a piece of state. I'm rendering a list of courses and depending on which stage (1-9) the courses comes under in the curriculum, I want to have a different colour border for the course.

```
<template>
  <div class="course-list">
    <div class="course-card" :class='borderClass[course.stage]' v-for="course in courses" :key="course.id">
      <div class="card-header">Stage {{course.stage}}</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{course.title}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{course.creator}}</p>
        <p class="card-text">{{course.hours}} Hours</p>
        <div class="add-btn" :class='bgClass[course.stage]'><i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x"></i></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I'm using v-bind to dynamically add the border-stage class.

```
  data() {
    return {
      borderClass: {
        '1' : 'border-stage1',
        '2' : 'border-stage2',
        '3' : 'border-stage3',
        '4' : 'border-stage4',
        '5' : 'border-stage5',
        '6' : 'border-stage6',
        '7' : 'border-stage7',
        '8' : 'border-stage8',
        '9' : 'border-stage9',
      }
}
}
```

Then in a sass file:

```
// Stage borders
.border-stage1 {
  border-top: 8px solid $red;
  border-right: 8px solid $red; 
}

.border-stage2 {
  border-top: 8px solid orange;
  border-right: 8px solid orange;
}

.border-stage3 {
  border-top: 8px solid orangered;
  border-right: 8px solid orangered;
}

.border-stage4 {
  border-top: 8px solid $green;
  border-right: 8px solid $green;
}

.border-stage5 {
  border-top: 8px solid $blue;
  border-right: 8px solid $blue;
}

.border-stage6 {
  border-top: 8px solid $teal;
  border-right: 8px solid $teal;
}

.border-stage7 {
  border-top: 8px solid $pink;
  border-right: 8px solid $pink;
}

.border-stage8 {
  border-top: 8px solid $info;
  border-right: 8px solid $info;
}

.border-stage9 {
  border-top: 8px solid #fff;
  border-right: 8px solid #ffff;
}
```

What I wanted to do initially was use template strings to do something like this 
`` :class=`border-stage{{course.stage}}` ``

But obviously that doesn't work, as i understand it i'm mixing css and js in a way that can't be done. Slightly confused here!

I know there must be a more efficient way of doing this but I can't figure it out! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer this.

```html
<template>
    <div class="course-list">
        <div class="course-card" v-for="(course, index) in courses" :key="index" :class="'border-stage' + course.stage">
        <div class="card-header">Stage {{course.stage}}</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">{{course.title}}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{course.creator}}</p>
            <p class="card-text">{{course.hours}} Hours</p>
            <div class="add-btn" :class='bgClass[course.stage]'><i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x"></i></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {}
    }
}
</script>

<style lang="sass">
    // Stage borders
    .border-stage1 {
    border-top: 8px solid $red;
    border-right: 8px solid $red; 
    }

    .border-stage2 {
    border-top: 8px solid orange;
    border-right: 8px solid orange;
    }

    .border-stage3 {
    border-top: 8px solid orangered;
    border-right: 8px solid orangered;
    }

    .border-stage4 {
    border-top: 8px solid $green;
    border-right: 8px solid $green;
    }

    .border-stage5 {
    border-top: 8px solid $blue;
    border-right: 8px solid $blue;
    }

    .border-stage6 {
    border-top: 8px solid $teal;
    border-right: 8px solid $teal;
    }

    .border-stage7 {
    border-top: 8px solid $pink;
    border-right: 8px solid $pink;
    }

    .border-stage8 {
    border-top: 8px solid $info;
    border-right: 8px solid $info;
    }

    .border-stage9 {
    border-top: 8px solid #fff;
    border-right: 8px solid #ffff;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the courses array contains courses of the same stage, filtered by a select menu, so this doesn't work.

Comment: I understand, in that case replace `index + 1` with `course.stage`, I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a template string if you use a v-bind like this:

```
<div class="course-card" :class="`border-stage${course.stage}`"
```

When using v-bind, the part between the quotes is just javascript.